# What other motives might there be to force an employee to quit or to fire them?

Tags: software-industry

I am employed in Washington state. 
I have an odd situation with an employer I have been with for over 4 years. I was in one department at the company the entire time. Recently the manager of the department left the company. I'm not certain of the nature of their departure. There had been a fair amount of other attrition, both voluntary and involuntary, so we are a shell of our former size. We were in a kind of limbo for a few weeks. Then we were told that our department was being dissolved and we were being promoted to new job titles in a different department. I didn't understand this, as we were all expecting layoff notices after the department manager left the company. In addition I'm not trained in this new job title.
Fast forward 8 weeks when I was put on report for not being able to contribute adequately in my new role. I never sought this role and never claimed to be adequately trained for it.
My reviews have always been great with the managers I've had there.
I'm assuming they want to drive me to quit or to fire me with cause.
I can only guess as to their motives:

- avoid paying severance
- avoid paying unemployment
- cause me to lose the options I was granted when I joined the company

Are there any other motives they might have? And what should I do about it?

Comment: I don't know about Washington in particular, but in many states a company's unemployment insurance premiums will go up if they lay off people, or fire them without cause (thus making them eligible for unemployment benefits).  If the employee quits, though, they aren't eligible for unemployment.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're overthinking this.

They wanted to dissolve the department. That means they're getting rid of it. Instead of laying you all off, they gave you another chance to try and see if you could contribute in a different position. That may not be working out, and they may have to get rid of you then. It doesn't strike me as particularly retaliatory.

Now, it may very well be. It may even be a combination of both. Maybe they though: "Let's give these people who no longer have a place in our company in their former roles a shot at another position, see if they're good at it. If not, we even get to avoid severance/unemployment."

In any case, whether or not what they're doing is legal can only be determined by a lawyer. So if you want to explore that avenue, you'll have to get one.

Otherwise, the writing is on the wall for you. You know what's likely happening, so prepare for it and find another job.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two choices

1. Adapt - Start learning about the new role/technologies. Put in some extra time to overcome the hurdle
2. Get a new job - Put in some extra time to beef up the CV and do job searching

It is your choice

But I also think that they are trying to get out of paying redundancy pay.

Answer (score 1):

Severance is not an entitlement, so that's out.  If they terminate you, you can draw unemployment, so that's out.  Options aren't usually worth the paper they're printed on, and that assumes you have anything in writing about them in the first place.

That said - they really didn't need your department.  This sounds like a startup situation.  They've tried to be nice and fit you elsewhere to save on recruitment costs, but it's not an optimal fit.  So here you are.

Start looking.  Maybe you'll get a severance, and maybe not.

Comment: You cannot collect unemployment in all places for termination with cause.